# whats the difference between below declaration in Java script

Tags: javascript

whats the difference between the 2 below declarations?

```
var vehiclePrototype = function{
    function init(carModel) {
        this.model = carModel;
    }


};
```

and

```
var vehiclePrototype = {
    init: function (carModel) {
        this.model = carModel;
    }

};
```

Comment: the first isn't even valid JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first, `init()` is only available within the outer function.  `vehiclePrototype.init()` won't work.

In the second, you are creating an object and assigning a function to the `init` property.  `vehiclePrototype.init()` will work.

Also, you have a syntax error in your first example.  You would need to use `var vehiclePrototype = function () {` for your first line.

Comment: "is only available within the closure" --- it's just an anonymous function, not a closure.

Comment: I apologize, I thought the term applied here.  Can you elaborate on the difference?

Comment: Closure = function that accesses (closes over) its outer scope.

Comment: @zerkms Closure is not the variable. Closure is the function.

Comment: It's my understanding that having the function creating a scope, a closure object is created internally, allowing inner code to access the outer variable values.  Is this incorrect?

Comment: [closure is when] an inner function always has access to the vars and parameters of its outer function, even after the outer function has returned -crockford

Comment: Oh, seems like I was wrong :-S https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures "A closure is a special kind of **object that combines two things**: a function, and the environment in which that function was created"

Comment: @zerkms wikipedia will do? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science) "In computer science, a closure (also lexical closure or function closure) is a function or reference to a function ..."

Comment: @zerkms, I'm looking at the example given on the Mozilla documentation, and I don't see how it is any different than the first example here.  Is it because the closure does not exist until the function is assigned to a variable?  That doesn't make much sense in my mind.

Comment: @Brad: the nested `init` function doesn't use any variables out of its scope.

Comment: @zerkms, Even though it doesn't, does that closure object not exist?  I thought it would, with `init` being the only member.

Comment: @Brad: I'm not sure about particular internal JS engine point of view, but from terminology point of view - as long as it only uses variables from its scope - it's just a function, not a closure.

Comment: @Brad The javascript engine doesn't need to link `init` or `vehiclePrototype` to their outer scope, because the functions don't access their outer scope. This makes them non-closures from _some_ points of view.

Comment: @JanDvorak, Interesting.  I figured the JavaScript engine would be more naive.  Thanks!

Comment: @Brad One more thing: If the engine realises no function that closes over some function's variables may outlive the function, it may decide to keep the variables on the stack (which is not possible if they're closed over by a proper (long-lived) closure).

Answer (score 2):

First of all the top is broken, so naively the top is broken and bottom is an object literal containing a function.

Assuming correct syntax the first still doesnt do anything, because init is scoped to the function and has no way of escaping to the outside. The difference is the top is an empty function which is different than an object literal containing a function.

Perhaps you wanted this:

```
var vehiclePrototype = function () {
    this.init = function (carModel) {
        this.model = carModel;
    };
};
```